# Was Frodo Baggins in the original version of The Hobbit?

Tags: plot-explanation, book-adaptation, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-hobbit

I see from the trailers for the new Hobbit film that Frodo Baggins is in it.

It has been a while since I read the book but I don't remember Frodo being in it.

Was his addition only for the movie adaptation or was he in the story all along?

Comment: I think he was mentioned, but did *not* play a major part of this.  Just my assumption from what I remember from the book.

Comment: So,that's why on the lego hobbit,he said:"my dear frodo",and it makes sense that LOTR is the "newest"version of the hobbit.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It looks like Frodo is being shoe-horned into *The Hobbit* to keep audiences happy (general audiences, mind you, not LotR fans who are not pleased with this news).

According to a report from [AICN](http://www.aintitcool.com/node/51787):

*What’s Frodo doing in The Hobbit? I don’t want to spoil too much, but I can say that Frodo is part of the connecting tissue between The Hobbit and Fellowship of the Ring.
In fact, the next shot was an over the shoulder on Elijah Wood hammering a sign up on Bag End’s front gate: “No Admittance Except On Party Business.” You guys should have an idea where that puts this moment in the timeline*

Extrapolating from this tidbit, I believe it is safe to say that 'Elderly Bilbo' (Ian Holm has already filmed his scenes in London) will be recounting his tale to Frodo before the party that we see in *Fellowship of the Ring*. The events of The Hobbit took place 60 years before the *Lord of the Rings* trilogy (and 28 years before Frodo was born) - so this explanation seems to make the most sense.

In answer to your original question - he was only added for the movie adaptation.

BTW - the same goes for Legolas...

Comment: I'm curious if we'll see Legolas in Mirkwood.  He is clearly old enough to have been around during the events, maybe he'll pop up in his father (the king)'s court?

Comment: I'm trying to keep this reply spoiler-free, but 'yes' to your first sentence.